# Extract information from JavaScript function in terms of country, state, city and locality which directly gives full address in Spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, google-maps, spring-mvc

I have to add country, state, city,and remaining address if it contains. But I'm not proficient in using Google API along with JavaScript. I'm using ready made JavaScript function which gives full address on textbox after using autocomplete.

I don't know how to take or extract the country, state, city from full address.

I am giving my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding-left: 14px;  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
        width: 401px;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
}

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
    zoom: 13
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));

  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
   // alert("here is your addresss :" address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="type-selector" class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
      <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
      <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for giving reply. From this output on search locality I want to extract individual county ,state,city and locality and use in Spring MVC class pojo.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the section of code (from what you gave) that you should be interested in.

```
var address = '';
if (place.address_components) {
  address = [
    (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
    (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
    (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
  ].join(' ');
}
```

Essentially, what this part does, is it initializes the **address** variable (empty initially). Then, if the **place** object (presumably returned from Google) is not empty and contains components, if fills the **address** with all the separate components from **place**.

The above code implies that the **place** object returned by Google provides you with three (3) components specifically: those at index positions 0, 1, and 2.

You will have to figure out if these components, on their own, give you the separated information you need. To check that, try updating with the following code (notice the FOR loop I added):

```
var address = '';
if (place.address_components) {
  address = [
    (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
    (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
    (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
  ].join(' ');

  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++)
  {
      console.log('Component at index ' + i 
        + ' is: ' + place.address_components[i].short_name;
  }
}
```

Run the updated code and check your console (available with Chrome) -- it will let you know which components were returned by Google, with their index number. Use that knowledge to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply....please copy whole code in html file run it..the enter any area .from this output on search locality i wanna to extract individual county ,state,city and locality and use in spring mvc class pojo.